# deedle aggregate/group based on running numbers in a column of Frame

Tags: f#, aggregate, deedle

say I have a `Frame`, which looks like below,

```
  "     Name    ID     Amount
0 -> Joe        51       50    
1 -> Tomas      52       100

2 -> Eve        65       20   

3 -> Suzanne    67       10 

4 -> Suassss    69       10 
5 -> Suzanne    70       10 

6 -> Suzanne    78       1 
7 -> Suzanne    79       10 
8 -> Suzanne    80       12

9 -> Suzanne    85       10 

10 -> Suzanne    87       10 
...
```

What I would like to achieve is to group or aggregate base on the `ID` column such that if a sequence of running number is encountered, those rows should be grouped together, otherwise, the row itself is a group.

Comment: You have attempted to find solution (except for the question here)?

Comment: what i can think of is to get a new column of dif of ID column, group based on if dif is 1, but i am not sure how to chunk these into different groups of 1s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive a recursive function is your friend here.

Feed a list of tuples

```
let data = [(Joe, 51, 50);
            (Tomas, 52, 100);
            (Eve, 65, 20);
            (Suzanne, 67, 10)]
```

to a function

```
let groupBySequencialId list =
    let rec group result acc data lastId =
        match data with
        | [] -> acc :: result
        | (name, id, amount) :: tail ->
            if lastId + 1 = id then
                group result ((name, id, amount) :: acc) tail id
            else
                group (acc :: result) ([(name, id, amount)]) tail id

    group [] [] data 0
```

and you'll get the result you are looking for.
[image: Grouped result]

This should get the job done save three caveats.

1. You need to parse your string into the tuples required
2. There's an empty list in the result set because the first recursion wont match and appends the empty accumulator to the result set
3. The list will come out be reversed

Also note that this is a highly specialized function.
If I was you, I'd try to make this more general, if you ever plan on reusing it.

Have fun.